# Finding associations using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have associated IDs in a csv format.

For example :

```
ID, Associated_ID
1,2
3,4
8,1
2,100
100,100
8,101
200,200
```

I want to get all associated IDs.

In this case, the expected result is:

> [1,2,8,100,101]
>
> [3,4]
>
> [200]

```
load csv from 'file:///test/test.data'  AS line 
CREATE (:ids { mc: line[0], associated_mc:line[1]})
MERGE (m1:id {name: line[0]}) 
MERGE (m2:id {name: line[1]}) 
MERGE (m1)-[:SAME]->(m2);
MATCH p=(a)-[r:SAME*]-(b) RETURN p;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a database and retrieving it in a single query.
**You should run separate queries these two.**

You don't need to write CREATE when creating nodes MERGE will do same avoiding duplicates. So you can **load data with the following query**:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///test/test.data'  AS line 
MERGE (m1:id {name: toInt(line[0])}) 
MERGE (m2:id {name: toInt(line[1])}) 
MERGE (m1)-[:SAME]->(m2);
```

**And get the required result with the following query:**

```
MATCH p=(start:id)-[:SAME*]->(end:id)
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS ((end)-[:SAME]->()) 
    AND 
    NOT EXISTS ((start)<-[:SAME]-()) 
return EXTRACT(node IN nodes(p) | node.name)
```

> If you don't put where condition you will get too many paths of which are
>   part of other longer paths. You can verify results by removing `WHERE` condition

Comment: Thanks. I am having a difficult time understanding the not exists clause. Is it similar to the one in SQL? I have updated the sample data in the question. This solution doesn't seem to work for it.

Comment: This would not work **if end nodes have relationships to themselves of paths are cycles.**  You need to remove the `WHERE`  condition in that case

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

```
MATCH (m:id)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(m, {relationshipFilter:'SAME'}) YIELD nodes
with EXTRACT(node IN nodes | node.name) as ex_nodes
return  distinct apoc.coll.sort(ex_nodes);
```